# Why is my ::before working but not my ::after not. Help css hivemind

Tags: html, css

dealing with some typography stuff this morning. How come only my .quote::before is working. http://codepen.io/samducker/pen/WpoBOB

EDIT: When I resize it starts appearing below the first line when the text wraps.

```
<h1 class="quote">&ldquo;Drink better not more&rdquo;</h1>
<p><span class="first-letter">A</span> week designed for cocktail lovers, Loves Cocktails is an exciting new 7-day
long festival arriving in Nottingham this April.</p>

.quote {
  font-family: $serif-font;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 0.3em 0em;
}
.quote::before, .quote::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 8px;
    width: 32px;
    background: #ec3723;
  }

p {
  max-width: 40em;
  margin: auto;
}

.first-letter {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about your `::after` element been rendered on resize is because you are not using `top` property for your `absolute` positioned element. You need to do something like

```
.quote {
  position: relative;
  /* other properties here */
}

.quote::before, 
.quote::after {
  top: 0;
  /* other properties here */
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o0ws7egp/)

By default, your `absolute` positioned element renders alongside your text, so when it wraps, and since you don't have `top` defined, your `::after` pseudo was breaking. In order to fix it, I defined `top` so that no matter how much your text wraps, pseudo elements stay in their place.

---

As you commented. Over here, I added another declaration where am trying to pull down the `::after` pseudo. Also note that am setting `top: auto;` for `::after` pseudo because we are setting `top: 0;` initially.

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/o0ws7egp/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am looking to create a small line below(after) the text so mirrored to the one above it. Not remove the one on resize.

Comment: Got it, wait will fix

Comment: @SamDucker Done

Comment: Legend! You just had to define the bottom on the ::after and set the quote as relative. What is the top: auto; doing? Many thanks!

Comment: @SamDucker I've explained, `top: auto;` is used because when you set `bottom: 0;` it won't move to `bottom` because we've `top: 0;` defined, so to reset that, I make it `auto`